# Website Redirection in Google Search

Tags: html, google-search

My problem is whenever I search any related keyword about my website in google, it will display the content and address of the website but if I click the link it will redirect to another website which is not related to my website.

[Click this to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5gLi.png)

Comment: https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/190597?p=ws_hacked&rd=1

Answer (score 0):

This most likely is Google's problem. In other words, I don't think there is anything you can do.